# How to compare two lists and print non shared values

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to write a simple program that just runs through a list of strings and compares each one to a shorter list of strings that contain some of the same words. I then want to print out all of the words in the long list that aren't in the shorter list. I think I have the right logic but I cant seem to get the printing to work. Here is what I have:

```
oneList = ['egg', 'duck', 'cow']
twoList = ['egg', 'giraffe', 'cow', 'poo', 'speaker']

for twoString in twoList:
    for oneString in oneList:
        if (twoList[twoTicker] = oneList[oneTicker]):
            #do nothing
        else:
            #do nothing
    #if it reaches end of list and isnt there, print word.
```

Answer (score 2):

- This answers the question as it was written.

  - *runs through a list of strings and compares each one to a shorter list of strings that **contain some of the same words***
  - *print out all of the words in the long list **that aren't in the shorter list***

## Use [Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)

- Use `not in`

  - `in` checks a value for membership in another value.
  - In this case, if a value in `b` is not in `a`, print it.

```py
a = ['egg', 'duck', 'cow']
b = ['egg', 'giraffe', 'cow', 'poo', 'speaker']

for v in b:
    if v not in a:
        print(v)


giraffe
poo
speaker
```

## Using a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```py
result = [v for v in b if v not in a]

print(result)

['giraffe', 'poo', 'speaker']
```

## Using [`set`](https://realpython.com/python-sets/)

```py
set(b) - set(a)

{'giraffe', 'poo', 'speaker'}
```